# Flutter Dropdownmenu, certain items in array cannot be outputed

Tags: flutter

I have a list of reasons stored in my form controller using GetX

```
class formController extends GetxController {


  String rejectreason1 = "Overheat";
  List reasons = [
    "Broken",
    "Missing",
    "Wet Wiring",
    "Overheat",
    "Orange",
    "Obergene"
  ];
```

Widget Class:

```
class ReasonForm extends StatelessWidget {
  formController formC = Get.put(formController());

  ReasonForm(this.index, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Form(
      // key: formKey1,
      child: Column(children: [
        DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(icon: Icon(Icons.event)),
          value: "Overheat",
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          items: formC.reasons.map((value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: value.toString(),
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            formC.rejectreason1 = value!;
            print("Selected ${value}");
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

and in the dropdown list with it being mapped when onChanged is called all the values can be stored and printed out but for some reason the item "Overheat" doesn't work. Other words such as "Others" also doesn't work either, but all the rest like orange, missing and others can be selected and printed out in the console.

Comment: Could you please add more code, maybe we can help :)

Comment: Sorry yeah i updated the question with both the controller code and widget code

Comment: What does your `formC.update()` do?

Comment: That part was supposed to be used to rebuild the widget as part of GetX though after further looking that part is redundant in this case

Comment: remove `formC.rejectreason1 = value!;`, see what `print("Selected ${value}");` printed.

Comment: It has the same effect , thought after experimenting by instead of storing the value in a variable I decided to append it into a list. The variable does indeed get stored in the list and can be used just that for some reason certain words can't be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you put `value: "Overheat"`, so you can't change it because `onTap` function change `formC.rejectreason1` but you dont put that value on your dropdown. Try to change it to `value: formC.rejectreason1`